# Debugging Backtrace gives weird line numbers

Tags: debugging, fortran, disassembly, intel-fortran, backtrace

**NOTE:** While I mainly focus on using GDB as a debugger in this question, I've noticed the same behavior in other debugging tools (Forge DDT does the same thing as well)

I'm trying to troubleshoot some really old Fortran code with GDB.  It isn't actually crashing, just printing a non-descriptive "Error Encountered" message on stdout.

I've isolated the subroutine that prints the non-helpful error message, and am trying to use GDB backtrace to figure out what's actually happening when it stops.  Except, the backtrace keeps point back to a nonsensical section of code when it fires.  It may look something like this in my `progmain.F` file:

```
...
246       inum=number
247       number=number-1
248       call func
249       call error(999,0,0,0,zero,'func')
...
```

then I have another source file `helper.F` with:

```
722       subroutine error(num,i1,i2,i3,r,c)
```

This will correspond to a gdb output of:

```
(gdb) break error
(gdb) run
Breakpoint 1, error (num=999, i1=0, i2=0, i3=0, r=0, c=..., .tmp.C.len_V$757=6)
    at helper.F:722
722           subroutine error (num,i1,i2,i3,r,c)
Missing separate debuginfos, use: zypper install libgcc_s1-debuginfo-10.3.0+git1587-1.6.4.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  error (num=999, i1=0, i2=0, i3=0, r=0, c=..., .tmp.C.len_V$757=6)
    at helper.F:722
#1  0x00000000004036a2 in progmain () at progmain.F:246
...
```

Note that line 246 in `progmain.F` is not a call to `error`, it's an assignment operator 3 lines above what I presume is the call to `error` that triggered the breakpoint.

The issue is, sometimes it isn't obvious which call to `error` is triggering the breakpoint.  In particular, one breakpoint trigger has a backtrace that leads to the middle of a bunch of commented lines in `progmain.F` which are in between calls to `error`--and the code itself is RIFE with `go to` jumps so I can't actually tell what call to `error` is actually triggering the breakpoint.

Why are the line numbers inaccurate?  How can I make `bt` actually point back to the line where `error` was called?  I'm compiling with `-O0` and `-g` so it shouldn't be an optimizer issue...

**UPDATE:** Following a comment in response to this thread, I tried doing a `frame 1` command followed by `disas /m` in gdb.  I then paged through the assembly code until I reached the section of code in question  The `disas` output looks like:

```
245           x=0
   0x00000000004036d7 <+359>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000004036dc <+364>:   call   0x5d0dbf <func>
246           inum=number
   0x00000000004036e1 <+369>:   add    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
   0x00000000004036e5 <+373>:   mov    $0x75a988,%eax
   0x00000000004036ea <+378>:   mov    $0x75a984,%edx
   0x00000000004036ef <+383>:   mov    $0x75a984,%ecx
   0x00000000004036f4 <+388>:   mov    $0x75a984,%ebx
   0x00000000004036f9 <+393>:   mov    $0x11096c0,%esi
   0x00000000004036fe <+398>:   mov    $0x75a3e0,%edi
   0x0000000000403703 <+403>:   movq   $0x6,(%rsp)
   0x000000000040370b <+411>:   mov    %rdi,-0x5a8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000403712 <+418>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000403715 <+421>:   mov    %rsi,-0x5a0(%rbp)
   0x000000000040371c <+428>:   mov    %rdx,%rsi
   0x000000000040371f <+431>:   mov    %rcx,%rdx
   0x0000000000403722 <+434>:   mov    %rbx,%rcx
   0x0000000000403725 <+437>:   mov    -0x5a0(%rbp),%rax
   0x000000000040372c <+444>:   mov    %rax,%r8
   0x000000000040372f <+447>:   mov    -0x5a8(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000403736 <+454>:   mov    %rax,%r9
   0x0000000000403739 <+457>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040373e <+462>:   call   0x644c45 <error>
=> 0x0000000000403743 <+467>:   add    $0x10,%rsp

247           number=number-1
248           call func
249           call error(999,0,0,0,zero,'func')
```

So if I'm reading this right, the assembly isn't happening in the same order as the original code.  The call to `func` is happening first, then `number` is being loaded and decremented, then `error` is being called, and I guess this re-arrangement is breaking the debugging symbols?  Why is this happening when I'm compiling without optimizations?

Comment: I cannot speak about Fortran but when debugging C/C++ binaries my advice for issues like this one (seemingly wrong line numbers or wrong values of variables) is: look at the disassembly, only this tells you the truth. The `/m` option of gdb's `disassemble` command might be useful to see which line is associated with which instruction. Feel free to add the output to the question if you are still stuck.

Comment: Ooo that both sounds both intimidating and potentially extremely useful.   I'll be back once I figure out how to disaaemble...

Comment: Like I said, gdb has a builtin command. When you are in the situation where you have created the backtrace in the original question, execute a `frame 1` followed by a `disas /m` and you should see the surroundings of the callsite of `error` in your `progmain` function.

Comment: When I do `frame 1` followed by `disas /m` it starts the dump all the way at the beginning of the `progmain` function, not the call-site of `error`.  It also does that when I do `disas 0x4036a2`.  This is so baffling...

Comment: Sorry, I have probably confused that with the behavior of the `list` command. You should refer to the documentation of the version of gdb that you are using or the builtin help.

Comment: According to documentation for GDB, `frame 1` followed by `disas /m` should be exactly what I need.   I think it's just that whatever is messing up the backtrace is also affecting `disas` and GDB is defaulting to giving a dump from the entirety of the `progmain` code because the program pointer where I'm asking for `disas` is junk nonsense.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint at `error`, and when it gets there, you ought to be able to do `x /s $r9` to print the string pointed to by `%r9` (the 6th argument)

Comment: The `gcc` man page also recommends using `-Og` for debugging, rather than `-O0`

Comment: @veryreverie Ah, I'm hitting the limit on the number of tags so thought I'd be better off with [intel-fortran]

Comment: A couple of other things you can do to potentially get more attention: first replace [backtrace] (12 watchers) with [gdb] (1.4k watchers). Then you probably want to provide a [mre] of the problem. Without an MRE, no-one can try this for themselves to investigate what's going wrong.